# Cost of living in the Netherlands vs Germany

Tags: eu, cost-of-living

From what I have seen many people consider Germany to be a cheaper country to live in as opposed to the Netherlands. I know its hard to compare two countries, but if I look at three aspects - cost of accomodation, groceries and transport, would Germany be cheaper than the Netherlands in general?

I am not comparing Munich, which I know is very expensive, but rather a city like Hannover, Ingolstadt or Hamburg compared to The Hague, Amersfoot in the Netherlands.

Comment: It should be possible to compare all 3 factors separately, I'd suggest asking 3 separate questions, this is likely to be closed as 'too broad'.

Comment: https://www.numbeo.com/cost-of-living/comparison.jsp

Comment: Jacob, I did have a look at numbeo.com - are those numbers accurate?

Comment: @9ilsdx 9rvj 0lo - I can close this question if the community considers it as too broad. I was interested in the opinions of people who has lived in both countries mentioned